# How can I show a grey transparent overlay in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I show a grey transparent overlay in C#?
It should overlay other process which are not owned by the application doing the overlay.

Comment: A little more information if you please... Do you want to control the transparency of your main application window ? Winforms 2.0 or WPF land ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a transparent window the size of the whole screen, mark it always-on-top, calculate the regions of your other application windows, and make the non-window regions of the top window grey.

I suppose you could just position your own application windows on top of the transparent grey one, with it being above all the other ones, but getting a tricky z-order scenario like that right, especially in conjunction with other apps that might also be doing z-order tricks, is tough.

Answer (score 1):

Here a little app which do more or less the functionnality you want :

http://www.anappaday.com/downloads/2006/09/day-10-jedi-concentrate.html

Comment: This was really helpful, and that app gives samples of hooking into the Keyboard, creating a transparent window, etc.

- Matthew